# Searching /etc/passwd for username

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to search the `/etc/passwd` file for a username that the use unputs but I'm not sure about the `if` statement syntax. My current code is:

```
print "Username?";
$username = <STDIN>;

open (PASSWD, '/etc/passwd')
     while (<PASSWD>);
          if (PASSWD ((split(/:/)[0] =~ $username)) {
               print ((split(/:/)[5]), "\n");
          }
close (PASSWD);
```

Something is wrong with the syntax and I'm having difficulty finding the correct way despite searching stackoverflow and google. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Search for [`chomp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#chomp)

Comment: Your `while` doesn't have a `BLOCK`! https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html

Comment: You're missing a semicolon on the line with `open`.

Comment: The `while` is getting interpreted as a statement modifier, but if you had used `strict` and `warnings`, you would have seen _readline() on unopened filehandle PASSWD_. Moral of the story: **always** use `strict` and `warnings`!

Comment: It kind of seems like you might just be guessing at Perl syntax and hoping that something will work...

Answer (score 2):

Perl has built-in functions for that, see [`getpwnam`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#getpwnam-NAME) or [`User::pwent`](http://perldoc.perl.org/User/pwent.html):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

print "Username? ";
chomp( my $username = <STDIN> );

die "Unknown user $username\n" unless getpwnam($username);

my $dir = (getpwnam($username))[7];
print $dir, "\n";

# - or -
use User::pwent;
print getpwnam($username)->dir, "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the missing semicolon at the end of your `open()` line is a typo.

Your `while` statement needs a block, not a semicolon.

```
while (<PASSWD>) {
  ... # stuff
}
```

When you run this line:

```
$username = <STDIN>;
```

Then `$username` will end containing all of the characters the user has typed at the command line. Crucially, that includes the newline character that was generated when they pressed the "Enter" key.

You then go on to compare that variable with the first field from the records in `/etc/passwd`. Those fields don't contain a newline character, so the match never succeeds.

You'll want to remove the newline from the end of `$username`. That's what `chomp()` is for.

```
chomp($username = <STDIN>);
```

Also, the `PASSWD` in your `if` statement is very strange. I'm not sure why you think it's necessary. It's not.

```
if ( (split(/:/)[0] =~ $username) {
```

But actually, a regex check is overkill here. You should be checking for string equality.

```
if ((split(/:/)[0] eq $username) {
```

A couple of other tips:

- Always `use strict` and `use warnings`.
- Use lexical variables for filehandles, use the three-argument version of `open()` and always check the return value from `open()`

  ```
  open my $passwd_fh, '<', '/etc/passwd'
    or die "Cannot open /etc/passwd: $!\n";
  ```